# How to change Android notifications sound intercepting them?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-application, android-tiramisu

I'm trying to intercept android's notifications and change their audio programmatically using `NotificationListenerService`.

I've tried using `NotificationListenerService` and change the `statusBarNotification` sound, but it doesn't seem to work.

```kotlin
class NotificationModifierService : NotificationListenerService() {
    private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        notificationManager = super.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return super.onBind(intent)
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val channel = notificationManager!!.getNotificationChannel(sbn.notification.channelId)
        channel.setSound(null, null)
        
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn)
    }
}
```

`channel` ends up being null, even though `sbn.notification.channelId` is not null, so I'm not able to change the sound...

I also tried to cancel the notification and create another one, I was able to cancel, but not able to create it...

```kotlin
    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        this.cancelNotification(sbn.key)
        
        // CREATE NEW CHANNEL HERE

        // ...
        
        notificationManager!!.notify(123, sbn.notification)

        Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to change your own notifications, or another app's?  I don't think you can change another app's.

Comment: I'm trying to change another app's notifications... through this, I'm able to completely cancel them, but I didn't find a way to modify it...